# How to align a picture,name and the post with css like facebook does?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align  a full name,picture and the post just like they do in most social networks (linked-in or facebook).But i cant align them the well.Can anybody please try to fill the gaps with necessary css commands?Thank you in advance.

```
<div>
 <span class="picture"> <img src="/assets/images/rails.png"/></span> 
  <a  href="#" class="user-name">user-full-name</a>
 <span class="post"></span>
 </div>
```

css

```
 .picture{height:40px;
         width:40px;
         } 

  .user-name{
         margin-bottom:35px;
            }
   .post{     }
```

Comment: Just look at the HTML and CSS that Facebook/LinkedIn/whoever uses, and mimic that, if that's the effect you're after.

Comment: @katie I only see a username field are you trying to positiong this in relation to the image rails.png or ? If you can clear this up I would be eager to help ;)

Comment: another thing im seeing here are spans ... cant say i know them THAT well .. but divs ( especially when working with reset frameworks ) are much more predictable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.inline_table{
  display: inline-table;
  position: relative;
}
```

is another property you might want to look at ... any element which has both position relative AND inline table .. will be aligned left to right butted up against each other.

so in this example:

```
<div id="profile_picture" class="inline_table">
<div id="profile_name" class="inline_table">
<div id="profile_post" class="inline_table">
```

will all be aligned along the same row

Answer (score 0):

```css
span.picture {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic example: http://jsfiddle.net/GU2aM/ to get you started.